# PHP - guess MIME type of image stored in variable

Tags: php, mysql, image, blob, mime

I'm storing small images in database (MySQL, `blob`), so when I retrieve any image it's in variable.

My plan is to display image with CSS as base64 encoded in background image: `background: url(data:image/…`.

To perform that I need to detect MIME type of image which is in variable. There's [exif_imagetype](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php), but it works only with files.

Is there any way to detect MIME type of image which isn't stored as file, but in variable?

Comment: why don't you store the mime type on upload?

Comment: @DanielA.White I can, but is there any way to perform MIME detecting on-the-fly without storing any unnessesary data in DB?

Comment: i wouldn't consider it "unnecessary", it would be an optimization.

Comment: @DanielA.White agree with you, it will be useful for optimization. But, anyway, I want to know is it possible to detect image MIME on-the-fly.

Comment: Is too slow if you don't save data in DB, and use imageGD function to detect MIME type. And this isn't optimized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`getimagesizefromstring`](http://php.net/getimagesizefromstring) to get information about an image blob, including the image’s MIME type. It is available since PHP 5.4.

However, I would also suggest to store the MIME type in the database. Heuristic approaches are “expensive” and storing a few bytes in the database is much more efficient than guessing the image type over and over again.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you @lxg!